# how tomcat is generating maximum threads? in which scenario it generates?

Tags: multithreading, tomcat

Recently due to following problem my website stopped working. After restarting tomcat my issue is solved, but I want to know why and when tomcat generates maximum threads.

The problem was as follows:

> Maximum number of threads (150) created for connector with address null and port 443

And suddenly my website stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

Few Pointers :

- Connectors are defined in server.xml file in $(TOMCAT_HOME)/conf directory. You can check the settings in this file and compare it with default connector setup.
- Usually number of threads is equal to the number of incoming requests to the Server. You can check if there is some script which is triggering such requests.
- you can also check if the request threads for the webapps are completing their processing normally and getting released for other requests.
- if you are using an IDE like eclipse, etc. to start tomcat, then you shall be able to see which threads are being generated when running in debug mode.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot Shailesh for the reply. I want to know the more details about your second point You can check if there is some script which is triggering such requests. how can i check?

Comment: It could be any client script which can make requests to the tomcat server. It can also be some Ghost script, Malware, etc which could be making http requests to your tomcat server.